# couchbase: design strategy for forward compatibility in clients

Tags: couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and am trying to learn about best practices in writing a mobile app where the application's business logic will evolve over time.  Reading [Couchbase's recommendations for design decisions](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/doc-design-considerations.html), I see that there are a variety of approaches, but I do not yet get a sense of how these approaches can vary over time.  For example, if I have a Beer-related application whose version is `0.0` and that represents beers within a brewery document and then in version `1.0` beers are split into separate documents with references in the brewery document, if half my user base is using `0.0` and half is using `1.0`, I can see how to make `1.0` backwards compatible with `0.0` but I can see now forward compatibility strategy for `0.0`.  It seems (naively) that the only solution is to force upgrade clients when the data model changes.

Has anyone run into this problem and, if so, is there a set of practices to solve it.